# Menu item in fragment not shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-menu

I am trying to add search button as menu item in a fragment with toolbar in the activity. This is the menu.xml file.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_white_24px"
    android:title="Search"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" />
```

In my fragment class I have added `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` inside the onCreateView method. And this is my onCreateOptionsMenu method in fragment class.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Searched everywhere and tried everything but the search button never appears. What could I be missing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

In Activity

```
  @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_dash_board, menu);
    // Retrieve the SearchView and plug it into SearchManager
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(SEARCH_SERVICE);
    searchView.setQueryHint("Search");

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
            .getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of do on `onPrepareOptionsMenu`.

```
@Override
public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem mSearchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.mi_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) mSearchMenuItem.getActionView();
}
```

Comment: @theanilpaudel Try to add super method inside it at last. I forgot to add that one.

Answer (score 0):

use the below code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
   inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your menu

```
<menu 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
     tools:context=".MainActivity">

<item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/seacrhlayout"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
</menu>
```

Your action layout

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/main">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/seacrh"
            android:src="@drawable/search"
            android:layout_width="14dp"
            android:layout_height="14dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Your oncreatemenuoption

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
            MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
            MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, R.layout.seacrhlayout);
            View view = (View) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(item);
            ImageView search=view.findViewById(R.id.seacrh);
            //do whatever you want to don on search button

        return true;
    }

// please check your tool bar color and the icon color of the search. may be due to color its not visible
```